# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function' k

Tags: python

I am a complete noob.  I am attempting to make a simple python program where I calculate the price of something.  I keep getting this error when attempting to call a function within a function.  Please see below:

```
def calculateTotalPrice(p,t):
    totalPrice = p * (1+t)
    return totalPrice

price = int(input("Enter the Price: "))

def confirmState():
    print("What state tax are we using? ")
    print("1.\tNY\t%8.75")
    print("2.\tNJ\t6.675")

    print("Enter Selection")
    stateSelection = int("> ")

    if stateSelection == 1:
        return int(0.0875)
    if stateSelection == 2:
        return int(0.0675)

    return -1

calculateTotalPrice(price,confirmState)
```

**THIS IS WHAT I SEE IN THE TERMINAL**

Enter the Price: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random_p2.py", line 22, in 
    calculateTotalPrice(price,confirmState)
  File "random_p2.py", line 2, in calculateTotalPrice
    totalPrice = p * (1+t)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'

Comment: Your `int` call after the `print("Enter selection")` line is evaluating the argument `"> "` and hence will result in the conversion error. From what I can tell of your code, it seems that you want the user to input a number - consider using `int(input("> "))` instead.

Comment: calculateTotalPrice(price,confirmState) - that is passing the function object represented by confirmState. The confirmState function itself is NOT being called/invoked, which is probably not expected..

Comment: Secondly, if you're using `int` with a float specified, it'll return the number as an integer without the floating points. Lastly, your `if` statement is incorrect - you should be using `elif` for the second `if` statement unless they're separate.

Comment: @Edric Thank you for the assistance!  I was able to get it to work the way it was intended!  Thanks!!

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you for your assistance as well!  I forgot the additional () when calling the confirmState function!

Answer (score 4):

You need to add parenthesis to the confirm state function to call it or set it to a variable earlier in the code. Would look something like this:

```
calculateTotalPrice(price, confirmState())
```